# localhost not starting after start-all.sh command

Tags: hadoop

I recently installed Hadoop, then I start hadoop using `start-all.sh` command, for the early stages it worked with 0 nodes, can be viewed on **localhost:50070**.
I tried to fix the *LiveNodes* = 0, by copy a folder to hadoop repo, but couldn't.

Then I tried to format nodes by `hadoop namenode -format` command.
Now the problem is localhost also not shows up.

What I did wrong? And how could I revert the operation.

Comment: Can you check log files for respective components when you try to start them?

Comment: I'm sorry , i have no idea of doing this.

Comment: Instead of start-all.sh use start-dfs.sh to start just the namenode,datanode and the secondary namenode.Browse to logs directory which resides in your installation directory for a manual installation, example path - /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/logs, check for logs respective to each component and see what error is preventing the components to get started.